# How to evenly extrude a mesh in geometry nodes?

Tags: modeling, geometry-nodes, solidify-modifier

Using Geometry nodes Extrude Mesh node, I can extrude a simple cube like so:

[image]

But the moment I introduce more geometry, for example by adding loopcuts to the cube, the extrude node deforms the new geometry. I guess it interpolates normals around the sharp edges which is why the extrusion looks a bit rounded like so:

[image]

If using solidify modifier instead, I can fix this issue by using the Even Thickness option in the modifier. Is it possible to recreate this option in geometry nodes?

[image]

Comment: Can you please describe your goal in more detail?

Comment: @quellenform The goal is to extrude the cube (or any geometry) in geometry nodes evenly, so that all the edges are straight. Like when using solidify modifier the even thickness setting. I'm asking how to recreate the even thickness setting from solidify modifier in geometry nodes.

Comment: Check mark individual. Then all faces extrude evenly

Comment: @TheJeran That option does not fill the corners, but I thought I might be able to scale the new geometry and merge by distance. It results in horrible internal geometry, but it kinda works https://imgur.com/a/WGhOuak.

Comment: So what is your end goal then? Just a larger cube?

Answer (score 2):

*Update 8/25/2003:*

- Here is a full setup for my solidify node.
  [image]
- this is how the node group looks
  [image]
- This how it looks compared to the solidify modifier
  [image]

---

*Original post:*

here is a true way to do it that is the same as the modifier.
[image]

if you want explanation then let me know

Comment: You'd wish it was that simple ...Unfortunately, the [Solidify](https://github.com/blender/blender/blob/main/source/blender/modifiers/intern/MOD_solidify_extrude.cc) modifier (especially with "Even Thickness") is a bit more complicated, and all the answers given here do not lead to the goal. But anyway: still a nice solution!

Comment: it is close, though for how simple it is

Comment: when I say close I mean very close, and if do some adjustments it could get closer. I'll share a full setup later.

Comment: @quellenform I just checked it again and i retract what i said. this looks exactly the same as the modifier. (before my midlevel [offset] was different so it looked different). (this is as of now) (actually it is this similar 

Comment: anyway you'll see

Answer (score 1):

With this solution you can't reproduce it 100%, but it works sufficiently well in most cases:

Just capture the normals of each point, scale them, and use this vector in the node `Set Position`.

This offsets the points along their normals by a certain value.

[image]

Alternatively, you can use the `Scale Elements` node, and then send the original mesh with the scaled version to the `Mesh Boolean` node.

[image]

But the main problem remains in any case: The scaling is not 100% with constant thickness, but it comes close.

Comment: Scaling along the normals results in the same uneven surface on meshes like the subdivided cube. The inner, original cube has straight faces, while the larger cube that has been scaled up has uneven, almost round shape. https://imgur.com/kBAb8XH

Comment: It's also scaling the object, while I would prefer extrusion. So that the original surface is connected with the new extruded surface.

Comment: @aphatetic_artist Ah, now I understand what you mean ;-) In this case you can use the node `Scale Elements` in combination with `Mesh Boolean`. Otherwise I'm afraid there is no (easy) possibility in Geometry Nodes.

Answer (score 1):

In case of a cube, you can stack it like that:

[image: node setup]

[image: result]